# IntelliJ: PhoneGap build throws com.android.prefs.AndroidLocation$AndroidLocationException

Tags: android, cordova, intellij-idea

- IntelliJ IDEA CE 2017.2
- Android API 24
- Mac OSX Sierra 10.12.6

When attempting to launch a phonegap app pulled from a git repo, the app crashes during the android build with the following console message:

```
Error:Internal error: (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException) com.android.prefs.AndroidLocation$AndroidLocationException
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:  com.android.prefs.AndroidLocation$AndroidLocationException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.android.AndroidJpsUtil.getAndroidTarget(AndroidJpsUtil.java:404)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.android.AndroidJpsUtil.getAndroidPlatform(AndroidJpsUtil.java:480)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.android.builder.AndroidPreDexBuildTarget.computeRootDescriptors(AndroidPreDexBuildTarget.java:110)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.builders.impl.BuildRootIndexImpl.addRoots(BuildRootIndexImpl.java:72)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.builders.impl.BuildRootIndexImpl.<init>(BuildRootIndexImpl.java:62)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.load(BuildRunner.java:84)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:267)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:125)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0(BuildMain.java:236)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.service.impl.SharedThreadPoolImpl.lambda$executeOnPooledThread$0(SharedThreadPoolImpl.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I don't speak Java, so this message means nothing to me. I've tried removing/reinstalling the IDE, Java, android, and cordova with no success. The same codebase works for my teammates, so I think it has to be a configuration issue on my machine. I've researched every permutation of this error for the last 8 work hours. I switched SDK versions, IntelliJ versions (2016.2) which failed with a `cordova.jar` error - but one problem at a time, please, Java versions (1.6), and even code git branches.
I'm out of ideas. Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you try importing the project instead of pulling from a git repo?

Comment: See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-176144.

Comment: Holy crap I lost so much time tracking down that issue. Beers to you, @CrazyCoder.