# AndroidLocationException caught while building project

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

I have a none gradle android project with some gradle based modules. But when I'm trying to build the project with intellij IDEA 2017.2 I'm getting this Error:

The android sdk version is 25.0 and also there is no access to internet because of some rules and privacy at office.

Even I tried this project in android studio but no chance.

```
Error:Internal error: (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException) com.android.prefs.AndroidLocation$AndroidLocationException
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.prefs.AndroidLocation$AndroidLocationException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.android.AndroidJpsUtil.getAndroidTarget(AndroidJpsUtil.java:404)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.android.AndroidJpsUtil.getAndroidPlatform(AndroidJpsUtil.java:480)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.android.builder.AndroidPreDexBuildTarget.computeRootDescriptors(AndroidPreDexBuildTarget.java:110)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.builders.impl.BuildRootIndexImpl.addRoots(BuildRootIndexImpl.java:72)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.builders.impl.BuildRootIndexImpl.<init>(BuildRootIndexImpl.java:62)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.load(BuildRunner.java:84)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:267)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:125)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0(BuildMain.java:236)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.service.impl.SharedThreadPoolImpl.lambda$executeOnPooledThread$0(SharedThreadPoolImpl.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Please add the details about your build gradle and code.

Comment: This link might be helpful : https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-176144

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/45463231/2000323

Comment: @Andrey there is no answer in the link you have sent.

Comment: The reason is mentioned here and there bug: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-176144. Try upgrading IJ or [this workaround](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-176144#focus=streamItem-27-2350619-0-0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue then i solved this problem by downgrading intellij idea from 2017.2.1 to 2017.1.1.

this link might be helpful  :

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-176144#focus=streamItem-27-2337702-0-0